# How to write data into Excel file and save it? EPPlus C#

Tags: asp.net, .net, excel, epplus

I have the code to execute multiple stored procedures from SQl. However, I am having an issue on how to write the data from the stored procedures into the Excel file. After writing the data into the excel file, I would like to save the Excel workbook. How can I achieve this? Any help is very much appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
    public static void ExecuteStoredProcedures()
    {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=the connection goes here.."))
            {
                SqlTransaction transaction;

                connection.Open();
                transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

                try
                {
                    SqlCommand cmdOne = new SqlCommand("exec ", connection);
                    SqlCommand cmdTwo = new SqlCommand("exec", connection);
                    SqlCommand cmdThree = new SqlCommand("exec", connection);

                    cmdOne.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmdTwo.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    cmdThree.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    transaction.Commit();              
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public static void SaveExcelFile()
        {

            string SheetLocation = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SheetLocation"];

            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(SheetLocation))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(SheetLocation);
            }

            ExecuteStoredProcedures(); //Should I call the method to load the data that comes from the stored procedures? Or what should I do to write the data into the file?

            var newFile = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\");

            using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
            {                         
                xlPackage.Save();
            }                     
        }
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation at all? It seems like you haven't tried anything.

Comment: Read the documentation and the examples. They *already* show what to do. EPPlus has a LoadCollection *and* a LoadDataTable that can load any data into an Excel range in a single call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get data from stored procedures in the form of a Dataset or DataTables.

Create worksheet:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
{                         
     ExcelWorksheet ws = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(AnyName);

}
```

Loop in Datatable rows and columns like a 2d array and create cells in the worksheet and add data in the created cells:

```
int rowIndex = 0
foreach (DataRow DataTableRow in dt.Rows)
{
    int colIndex = 1;
    rowIndex++;
    foreach (DataColumn DataTableColumn in dt.Columns)
    {
         var cell = ws.Cells[rowIndex, colIndex];
         cell.Value = DataTableRow[DataTableColumn.ColumnName];
         colIndex++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the built in method to load a DataTable?